# AJAX in Explorer 11

Tags: ajax, select, internet-explorer-11

can I ask for advice about why this code does not work in IE11? Chrome is all right.

This script filters items when writing text. I assume there will be some differences in the browser. Maybe just add some parameter?

Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input list="brow">
<datalist id="brow">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>  

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input").click(function(){
    $(this).next().show();
    $(this).next().hide();
});

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to make a test with your code in Chrome and IE 11. Based on my testing result, I find that your code is working fine in both browsers.

Testing result with chrome:

[image]

Testing result with IE 11:

[image]

In testing, You can see that it is working fine in IE 11. I suggest you to try to run the above code with IE and again try to check whether it is working or not. If issue persist than try to inform us the detailed information about your issue. You can also tell us if you see any error or warning message.

Comment: Thank you for testing. Unfortunately, it does not work when I only want to type "me" and it should find "Chrome". Chrome is OK, but IE11 does not work.

Comment: Looks like this is the issue with Ajax and not with IE 11. I also made a test with Chrome, MS Edge and FireFox. I find that, In Chrome it is working. In MS Edge it is not working. See here. https://i.postimg.cc/63xKKQ0n/65.gif In FireFox it is showing Chrome when I type ME. See here. https://i.postimg.cc/tTNKHN7G/66.gif So certainly there is some issue with Ajax because ME is not working properly with other browsers too.